# $PHP_SELF executing as soon as the page loads

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've created a HTML page to enter data to a MySQL database. I've embedded PHP code within the same HTML page. Here is the code,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php

/* Database connection operations */
require_once("db_handler.php");

$conn = iniCon();
$db = selectDB($conn);

?>

<b id="loc_caption_1">Enter a new location</b>
<div id="loca">
    <form name="locForm" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
        <table width="300" border="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Location ID</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lid" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $new_id; ?>" style="text-align:right" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="code" style="text-align:right" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Location</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="loc" style="text-align:right" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>
<br/>
<div id="buttons">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear" /> <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</div>
    </form>

<?php

/* Saving new record */
$id = $_POST["lid"];
$code = $_POST["code"];
$location = $_POST["loc"];

$query = "INSERT INTO locations(LID, Code, Location) VALUES('$id', '$code', '$location')";

if (!mysql_query($query, $conn))
{
    die("Error " . mysql_error());
}
else
{
    echo "<br/><br/>";
    echo "1 record added successfully!";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;URL=locations.php\">";
}

mysql_close($conn);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem I have is, the PHP code block which is written to insert the data to the database gets executed once as soon as the page loads. How can I stop this from happening? I want it to wait until I enter the data to the form and when I press the submit button, then gets executed.

Thank you.

Comment: `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First give a name to the post button like

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" name="GoBtn" />
```

Put the code to execute after submit inside the below wrapper

```
if(isset($_POST['GoBtn'])
{
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check whether any data was submitted and only then go to work:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code for saving data should be in `if (!empty($_POST))` block.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check is submit or not.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))  // Check if form submitted or not
{
  --- //Code for insert to database.
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

place the php code inside an IF

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ // if form is submitted
 // do insert things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You php page is interpreted as a flow : it means first displaying the form, then executing
the php code part, inserting null values (i guess).

in the script part you have to test if you are in a form display context or form submit context using something like :

```
if ($_POST) {
   // form submit context
}
```

Comment: there are now pasted here a lot of way to detect form processing context :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the submit button tag as:

```
<input type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Save" />
```

And prior executing the PHP code which inserts, check for submitForm as:

```
if(isset($_POST["submitForm"]){
//follow the insertion PHP code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You must check if there are variables available in $_POST before inserting into database.

   if(!empty($_POST["lid"])) {
   /* Saving new record */
   $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["lid"]);
   $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["code"]);
   $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["loc"]);

   $query = "INSERT INTO locations(LID, Code, Location) VALUES('$id', '$code', '$location')";

   if (!mysql_query($query, $conn))
   {
       die("Error " . mysql_error());
   }
   else
   {
       echo "
   ";
       echo "1 record added successfully!";
       echo "";
   }

   mysql_close($conn);
   }
2. Use mysqli_* functions, mysql_* functions are depreciated now.
3. use mysqli_real_escape_string() before inserting into database to prevent sql injection.
4. You should move this database insertion area to the top of the page and use "header('location: locations.php');" for redirection.

Comment: Yes, I know there is a lot more to be done and still I'm learning PDO. This is not for a big project, its just a small front-end I'm developing for a single MySQL database table. But thank you for all the advice. :)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the PHP code block depending on the existance of the posted data.
For refining you can even test the posted values semantically.

```
if ( (array_key_exists('lid', $_POST) 
AND  (array_key_exists('code', $_POST) 
AND  (array_key_exists('loc', $_POST) ) {
   then execute PHP code block
}
```